# wpf print / print preview usercontrol

Tags: wpf, printing, print-preview

I have to print to specified printer (price-label printer) some data.
Data looks like ean13 barcode, price, item's title, etc

I have a few settings what to print in each case.
What I want:

- create usercontrol (WPF) with 2 columns. left column for print preview, and right column for settings (checkboxes, textboxes).
- is user changes settings, print preview updates.

What approach should I use, to do it most right way?
Now printing routine looks like:

```
private void DrawOnGraphics(Graphics graphics)
{
    using (var shF = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(_barcode, new Point(0, 0));
// etc...
}
```

I think it's not very good code but it works here:

```
var pDoc = new PrintDocument();
pDoc.PrintPage += (a, e) =>
                              {
                                  DrawOnGraphics(e.Graphics);
                                  e.HasMorePages = false;
                              };
pDoc.Print();
```

Can I create one 'rendering routine' for both actions: print and printpreview?
Thanks.
How can it be done? Should I use in XAML for print preview

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=PrintPreviewImage}" />
```

or? :)

Main question is: how to draw own things (text, images, etc) for print and printpreview in WPF.

Comment: Should I draw desired image on canvas and use PrintVisual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this approach:

- in ViewModel, I have public property PrintPreview (of type Grid)
- in XAML i have

  ```
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=PrintPreview}" />
  ```
- each of settings are binded to ViewModel properties
- in private function I contruct PrintPreview property like this:

  PrintPreview.Children.Clear();
  var title = new TextBlock { ... };
  PrintPreview.Children.Add(title); //etc.
- I have "Print" method, that is binded to button "Print" in view:

  ```
  PrintQueue pq = new PrintServer().GetPrintQueues(new[]
                                                       {
                                                           EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections
                                                       }).FirstOrDefault(tmp => tmp.FullName.Contains("MyPrintername"));

  if (pq == null)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Please, setup printer");
      return;
  }

  var pt = new PrintTicket();
  // setting printticket
  pt.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(FromMMtoPx(96, WidthInMm), FromMMtoPx(96, HeightInMm));
  pt.CopyCount = Copies;
  pt.PageResolution = new PageResolution(203, 203);
  pt.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
  pt.PageBorderless = PageBorderless.Borderless;

  var pDoc = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
  pDoc.PrintQueue = pq;
  pDoc.PrintTicket = pt;

  // scale for whole printer page:

  var capabilities = pDoc.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(pDoc.PrintTicket);
  double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / PrintPreview.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight / PrintPreview.ActualHeight);

  PrintPreview.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
  var sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
  PrintPreview.Measure(sz);
  PrintPreview.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));
  pDoc.PrintVisual(PrintPreview, "MyPrint");
  ```

It works, but I don't really know, is that good approach or not.